# Why is $\sigma^2$ also the unconditional variance of $u^2$ in the homoskedasticity assumption in simple linear regression?

Tags: regression, econometrics

In Woolridge's econometrics book, he gives the homoskedasticity assumption

$${\rm Var}(u|x)=\sigma^2 .$$

He also says

> Because ${\rm Var}(u|x)=E(u^2|x) - [E(u|x)]^2$ and $E(u|x)=0$ then $\sigma^2=E(u^2|x)$. This means that $\sigma^2$ is *also* the **unconditional** expectation of $u^2$. Therefore, $\sigma^2 = E(u^2)$.

How do you derive that $\sigma^2 = E(u^2)$ from this? How do you drop the conditional on $x$ part?

Comment: Hint: what is the expectation of a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$${\rm E}(u^2) = {\rm E}[{\rm E}(u^2|x)] = {\rm E}(\sigma^2) = \sigma^2$$

Comment: What I don't understand is why $E(u^2) = E[E(u^2|x)]$

Comment: Michael: law of total expectation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Comment: @user542833 I'd never heard of that... makes sense now.